# Program compiling in Eclipse but not in Command Prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically, my program compiles and runs fine in Eclipse but doesn't compile in Command Prompt. It gives me Symbol Not Found with the pointer on the name of one of my classes. I've never had this happen before- the only difference between this program and the other ones I wrote is that I made a package in Eclipse for them. Any ideas?

Comment: if its compiling in eclipse its fine.Now a days there are lots of IDE's available which makes our work easy.Why you are going for command prompt.I would suggest you to always use IDE

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment, hence why I didn't post the code. We are allowed to use Eclipse and other IDEs but the grader must be able to compile in CMD

Comment: You are missing something from your `javac -classpath`

Comment: What does that mean? Edit: Oh, but I don't know what.

Comment: Can you tell how you are compiling

Comment: I'm just doing javac Foo.java when I'm in the directory on cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't set the path correctly.

[How to set Path in Java](http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java)

> The path is required to be set for using tools such as javac, java etc.
>
> If you are saving the java source file inside the jdk/bin directory,
>   path is not required to be set because all the tools will be available
>   in the current directory.
>
> But If you are having your java file outside the jdk/bin folder, it is
>   necessary to set path of JDK.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did that a long time ago. I've never had trouble compiling any other programs on this computer.

Comment: @Aire you got the solution ?

Comment: Umm... it doesn't give me any more errors but it doesn't create any .class files

Comment: @ Aire did you follow the comment by   Jesper in the accepted answer

Comment: Yes. It doesn't give errors but doesn't give .class files.

Comment: @Aire can pls tell the path that you set in enviromental variables

Comment: Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin

Comment: @Aire http://www.coderanch.com/t/416733/java/java/javac-making-class-file this will help you

Comment: I don't think that applies, since my path is set

Comment: Just noticed something- my class files were erased in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not do it already, it might help if you remove the package declaration in the java files. If your compiling class uses any other classes, they will not be compiled because of the package declaration. It happened with me once.